# Node server stop responding to requests after a while

Tags: node.js, http, express, https

I recently created an e-commerce site using express and the node server worked fine on my local machine. When I uploaded it to my VPS and tried running it using `pm2` and with `nodemon`, the server stopped responding to requests after few minutes, even when the number of requests is low.
Although all the internal functionalities other than request handling were working well. I used a lot of `console.log()`s in my codes, is this problem due to the excessive use of `console.log()`?